# How to truncate a table which has replication activated on it

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, replication, truncate

I have a database that once a week, I need to kill and feel its data. The tables in this database are being replicated into another database.

So whenever I try to truncate the tables, I get the error "*Cannot truncate table 'Test' because it is published for replication or enabled for Change Data Capture.*"

My guess is I should drop this table/article from the publication/replication list, and then truncate and add it back onto the list of publication/replication, How can I do this using T-SQL?

Questions Modified:

In addition to what was asked above, I need to say, currently, I am deleting data from the tables, but because I have millions of records in some of my tables it's a very time-consuming process.

What solution do you suggest for this situation?

Comment: Did you look at [`sp_droparticle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-droparticle-transact-sql) and [`sp_addarticle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql)?

Comment: Yes, @Aaron Bertrand, the problem is even after I drop the article using  "sp_droparticle", still, I cannot truncate it and get the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I do not recommend replication. It is slow, finicky, and has a lot of quirks like this that make it painful to manage. Mirroring/AG/Log Shipping are much better options if you can use them.

Don't have a setup on my person laptop so can't test this, but I have used this script numerous times at my previous company and it never failed. We had native replication (SQL Server to SQL Server) and I believe it was push so it may need to be tweaked for your environment

### Steps to Remove, then Reinitialize Article (table)

1. Pull table out of replication
2. Do whatever you need to do. Truncate, DDL, etc...
3. Add table back into replication and re-snapshot (reinitializes replication)

```
/*Run in context of publisher database where the article is located*/
Use YourDatabase
Go

/*Step 1: Inactivate the Article's Subscription*/
Exec sp_changesubstatus
    @publication = 'YourPublicationName'
    ,@article = N'YourTableName'
    ,@status = N'inactive'
Go

/*Step 2: Truncate table*/

/*Step 3: Put table back in replication*/
Exec sp_changesubstatus 
    @publication = N'YourPublication'
    ,@article = N'YourTableName',
    @status = N'active'
Go

/*Invalidate old snapshot*/
Exec sp_reinitsubscription
    @publication = 'YourPublication'
    ,@article = 'YourTableName'
    ,@subscriber = 'DestinationServerName'
    ,@destination_db = 'YourDatabaseName'
    ,@invalidate_snapshot = 1

/*Kick off the snapshot job. This identifies any tables with invalid snapshots and re-snapshots them.
WARNING this may re-snaphsot other tables that are also waiting for a snapshot, probably unlikely, but worth noting*/
Exec sp_startpublication_snapshot @Publication = 'YourPublication'
Go
```

### WARNING: Be Careful Running Snapshot in Production

One major warning I will give is be very careful running the snapshot job in a production environment. My previous company used to truncate and re-snapshot tables for years and years. Then one day, we found the snapshot job started high level table locks across every table in the subscription for significant periods of time. This caused massive deadlocking issues, and because replication is a system process, it was very tricky to identify the culprit in the deadlock analysis since it looked like our scripts were just conflicting with the database engine.

Comment: That's a pretty innovative answer.. I want to go try that now...

Answer (score 1):

Enable partition switching for publication:

```
EXEC sp_helppublication -- lists all publications
EXEC sp_changepublication 'myPublication', @property='allow_partition_switch', @value='true'
```

Then do a SWITCH of partition into empty dummy table, and drop the dummy table.
Effect is the same as truncate (very fast).
Should work on non-partitioned table too (try and let us know).